# Linux Kernel Code for USB modem

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, modem

I have tried using standard 3G USB modems on Ubuntu 11.04 which has linux kernel version 2.38.8. On analyzing packet spacings of a tcpdump capture, following pattern is observed
8094
14
4
6
3
3985
where we see very short packet spacing.

Above spacings is in microseconds for a 7 Mbps 3G connection. On changing the kernel to 2.6.39 , short spacings in tens of microseconds is no longer observed and is replaced by spacings in hundreds of microseconds. 
I have identified that changes were brought in 2.6.39 rc 1 update. But there are so many changes, that it is difficult to identify which caused this behavior.

So need information on what part of linux kernel source code to look for or which drivers or modules are used by 3G USB modem. Any help in locating code change is appreciated.

Comment: That really depends on what sort of device it is. Are you using PPP over it (ie. PPP over a tty, CDC ACM) or does it present a network adapter (ie. device uses CDC ECM)?

Comment: You might want to check packet timing on other interfaces too, before assuming it is unique to the USB modem drivers.  One obvious explanation for such traffic would be a mix of data chunks that fit in  one packet, with those that must be transported in several.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Linux USB serial drivers in `drivers/usb/serial`, there's a generic driver there (generic.c), but you're probably using one of the device specific ones (eg. option).